# Existence of Hamiltonian cycle in a 3-regular $C_n$-free graph

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

I know that Hamiltonian cycle problem in $3$-regular triangle-free graphs is $NP$-complete. I would like to know how far we can stretch this result. Observing that a triangle is just $C_3$ cycle, what is the longest fixed-length cycle $C_g$ such that deciding the existence of Hamiltonian cycle in $3$-regular $C_g$-free graphs is still $NP$-complete?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this paper "[Not Being (Super)Thin or Solid is Hard: A Study of Grid Hamiltonicity](http://research.cs.queensu.ca/~daver/MyPDF/superThin.pdf)" **Theorem 6.1** states that HCP (Hamiltonian Cycle Problem) for planar graph of maximum degree $3$ and girth $g$ (i.e. $C_{g-1}$-free) is $NP$-complete, for arbitrary $g>6$ (i.e. $g\geq 6$ in your notation).

So, in your notation, we are left with the undetermined cases of $g=4,5$.

So if you are willing to relax $3$-regular to $\Delta(G)=3$, then $g$ (actually $g+1$ for the girth value) can be arbitrarily large.